# Current scroll position updating with wrong number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on adding a class to the DOM when the scroll position reaches a certain number.  If the number is 150 or above, a class gets added.  If the number is less than 150, the class gets removed.  Currently, when I scroll down, all is well and the class gets added. However, when you scroll back up, if the number reaches a certain point, the scrollTop number bounces from one number to another repetitively.  This is my code:

*The Functionality*

```
const useVisibilityHook = threshold => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPos = () => {
      const currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
      console.log(currentPos, threshold);
      setVisible(currentPos > threshold);
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', getPos);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', getPos);
    };
  }, []);

  return visible;
};

const Banner = () => {
  const isVisible = useVisibilityHook(150);

  return (
    <div className={`violator ${isVisible ? 'hide' : ''}`}>
```

*What to update*

```
className={`violator ${!visible ? 'hide' : ''}`}
```

I'm not sure the best way to describe what I'm seeing, but basically. The currentPos variable will flip between a number like 124 and 292 respectively.  The numbers certainly change as you slowly scroll the page back up, but you get the idea.  This causes the class to toggle, which is no good.

*This is what I see over and over again*
[image]

Comment: The value of `prevPos` inside your `getPos` function will probably always have the initial value of 150. Can you try to log `prevPos` inside the function?

Comment: Sorry, I realized that variable wouldn't be getting updated so I've now updated my code above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem exactly though, you mention some scrollTop number, but it isn't visible in your code. I am also unsure what behavior you want, should the class be set/removed if the position is above/below 150 respectively? You mentioned that the class toggle is bad...

Comment: @pingeyeg You are missing the dependency array, That is why it is constantly rerendering.`useEffect(() => {}, []);`

Comment: I have updated my code above to reflect what you wrote so that it integrates with my code.  The dependency array is there, but still having the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding and removing scroll event listener on each render (whenever you set the state). You should lock the dependencies of the `useEffect` block, so it will only be called once.

I've create a custom hook `useVisibilityHook` that should do what I assume you want (I've used 300 as threshold to make the change point clearer):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const useVisibilityHook = threshold => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPos = () => {
      const currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
      setVisible(currentPos > threshold);
    }
  
    window.addEventListener('scroll', getPos);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', getPos);
    };
    
    getPos();
  }, []);

  return visible;
};

const App = () => {
  const isVisible = useVisibilityHook(300);
  
  return (
    <div className={`app ${isVisible ? 'show' : ''}`} />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```css
.app {
  height: 5000px;
  background: blue;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still getting the flashing of where the class is being added.

Comment: As you can see in the snippet, it works as expected. Check if something unmounts and then mounts your component. If so, calling `getPos()` when the `useEffect` block is created might help you.

Comment: So, the issue I'm seeing is when I add text within the div being returned.  If there isn't any text, all is well, but as soon as I add text, it flickers like crazy.

Comment: The content might change the height of the element. To test, set a constant height on the container, and see if it still happens.

Comment: Wow, yep, that's what it is.  Since I'm trying to hide the banner, which removes the all space, it's causing issues.

Comment: Use `visibility: hidden`, but leave it in place.

Comment: Am I adding that property to the container of the banner?

Comment: It seems like I should be setting the height of the box to make sure there is enough space to fill in.

Comment: To the class you use to show/hide, instead of `display: none`. The other option is setting a fixed height.